# Symfony2: No route found for "GET ..."

Tags: php, symfony

I implemented my own error-controller so I get an email when there is an error in my project. The project has been online for a while now and now and about once a day I get this error:

There was an error on /dealer/search/     No route found for "GET /dealer/search/"

This route doesn't exist, there is a route /deealer/search/top and /dealer/search/left. Nobody ever complained about an error occurring. This also happens with other pages and it is always the last part of the url that is missing.

It is an intranet which you can only access after logging in, so it can't really be a bot or something. I never received an email yet from someone who experienced this error, so I am a bit stuck where this is coming from.

Does anybody have any idea what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You did not need to implement a custom error controller for emailing. You already have the [Monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html) integrated into Symfony2  that can do this and much, much more.

It is quite possible that people just removed the last part of the URL to see what happens.

Comment: The Monolog was my first option, but I needed some other functionality on an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

These are exceptions thrown by the router when the page doesn't exists.

In other words, this is how Symfony signals **page not found** errors internally. By default it displays a `404 Not Found` page when these exceptions occur.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I just can't see how this error could be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most possible answer would be that the user manually entered the URL, as @Putr suggests already. You might want to check your server log files to see who made the request and how the user got there. You could also write a [functional test](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/testing.html#functional-tests) that checks all generated pages for the broken links. But that is probably a little too much.
In case you decide to do that make sure to check out the [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle)